# Java DOCX file Viewer

Tags: java, docx, docx4j, icepdf

Currently I'm developing an application that allows users to create a template and generate it into a DOCX file. The application needs to be able to display to users the changes in the template as the user is creating it.

The approach I tried was using DOCX4J library (allows manipulation of DOCX file) and ICEPDF which is primarily used to display the DOCX into the swing component by converting it first into a PDF file. Now the problem in this approach is that it loads pretty slow and some of the changes that occurs in the DOCX file does not reflect on the PDF conversion (example: dashed underline, font changes). When I tried to open the DOCX file ouput in MS WORD, the file is viewed correctly so I know changes do occur, but it seems that ICEPDF just can't show it properly.

So I was wondering if anyone knows a java library that allows DOCX files to be viewed directly from a Swing Component instead of converting it first into a PDF file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try docx4all or DocxEditorKit. Both of these are built around docx4j.